# How to fetch a data in flask to angular?

Tags: angular, flask

Is there a way I can fetch a data from flask and send it to angular?. The data will be use in one of my highcharts in angular.

Comment: If want your angular frontend to retrieve data from your flask backend use the fetch api. If you need flask to get data from other apis use python requests

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, **Angular** is client-side, **Flask** is server-side.

Fetching data from server-side into client-side, can be done through **RESTful APIs**, so we assume that your **Flask** app has some defined APIs that we can deal with from **Angular**.

You can have a look at RESTful APIs on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_introduction.htm).

After that, you have a look at declaring APIs in [Flask](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Finally, check [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) module in **Angular**.